# Write long string in file

Tags: python, string, for-loop, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a long string with following format:

PNT p1          -2.38165681          -1.52439231         100.00153552

PNT p6681          -2.38165681          -1.52439231         100.00153552

LINE L1 p1 p6681 10

PNT p2          -2.49447274          -1.66663147         100.00153552

PNT p6682          -2.49447274          -1.66663147         100.00153552

LINE L2 p2 p6682 10

PNT p3          -2.55804074          -1.56738209         100.00153552

PNT p6683          -2.55804074          -1.56738209         100.00153552

LINE L3 p3 p6683 10

PNT p4          -2.73659674          -0.71351200         100.00153552

PNT p6684          -2.73659674          -0.71351200         100.00153552

LINE L4 p4 p6684 10

PNT p5          -2.85359715          -0.92670064         100.00153552

PNT p6685          -2.85359715          -0.92670064         100.00153552

LINE L5 p5 p6685 10

PNT p6          -2.88783889          -0.81392658         100.00153552

PNT p6686          -2.88783889          -0.81392658         100.00153552

LINE L6 p6 p6686 10

PNT p7          -2.37194391           1.26905721         100.00153552

PNT p6687          -2.37194391           1.26905721         100.00153552

LINE L7 p7 p6687 10

PNT p8          -2.59158610           1.13472870         100.00153552

PNT p6688          -2.59158610           1.13472870         100.00153552

LINE L8 p8 p6688 10

...

The string will have about 10000 lines.

What is the fastest way to write such a string into a file?
And how would you write it?

Comment: `f.write(long_string)` where `f is a file open for writing should be adequate. What have you tried and what problem have you encountered? This seems like a fairly basic problem, so it isn't clear what your actual question is.  Are you uncertain about how file output works? Are you uncertain about how to join multiple lines into a single string?

Comment: okay. And do you have any advices how to build the string , because of the exact schema of the text file?

Comment: Note that how to build a long string is a very different question from how to write that string. You haven't given much context, but something like `'\n'.join(iterable of lines)` should work.

Comment: i'm uncertain about how to  join multiple lines into a single string

Comment: i don't know how `'\n'.join(iterable of lines)`  should look like. How should i build my `iterable of lines`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
with open("nameOfYourFile.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write(YourLongString)
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about that, I changed the code